# Iterating Specific Classes at Runtime Through a Global Variable

Tags: java, servlets, annotations

I am building a dependency injection framework and part of that process includes looping through all class files in the classpath and storing classes annotated with a specific annotation in an enumeration object. In terms of dependency injection, when a class is loaded, it finds all @inject notations and then searches through all the classes that contain an @injectResource notation, then returns the method values that I need to perform the DI portion.

My question is, it seems a lot more reasonable to build the enumeration class list at compile time, so that when my inject fields need to search those classes I don't have to search every class in the project every single time.

I figure I will build the class list at compile time through the servlet config, but where can I store this "global" list so that I can access it repeatedly throughout the project?

Off the top of my head, I am thinking that at compile time I will create a static class that contains the enumeration list, but I don't prefer to use static classes and i'm not sure if this is the most optimal approach.

Comment: The app context? Although if it's unchanging, who cares if it's a singleton/"static class" or not? One way or the other, if there's a single system of record, it's a singleton/"static class"/etc. -- don't fall in to the trap of thinking there's never a use for them.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Servlet Context, by the way, why shall you re-scan all classes everytime you create a new class? Why don't you keep references to the classes once, and use them (instead of hard-coding the classes list)?

Comment: That is precisely what this question is about. But I can't access the servlet context through a standard java class, and passing a reference in defeats the purpose of a dependency injection framework in the first place.

Comment: How would you access your DI container in a standard Java class? Is it by calling static methods?